# React html characters inside input placeholder

Tags: reactjs

How can I make the following work in React?

`<input type="text" placeholder="&#xf124; Location" />`

I looked at `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` but that is not for setting props such as `placeholder`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a JS string with escape sequence (I don't know what character `U+f124` is so I substituted `U+00C2` [`Â`], but it can be whatever code point):

```js
<input type="text" placeholder={"\u00C2 Location"} />
```